# Flex-Direction Column Reverse Works, but Need it to not auto scroll to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using a Flexbox that I need the contents to be reversed.  That is working great, but there are lots of items in the list and the newest ones are at the top.  Currently, the flex box autoscrolls to the bottom and I need it to start at the top.

Any suggestions?

```css
#viewed {
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    display: flex;
}
```

The new divs are pulled from Firebase dynamically.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: It would probably not autoscroll with this CSS code only. Something else makes it scroll. Please provide the relevant code, make a snippet (edit your question, there's a "code snippet" button)

Comment: Don't use column-reverse, reverse your array of data items and (optionally) limit the number of items before rendering

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? In our case we are using this to change layout for different devices

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
let viewed = document.getElementById('viewed');
viewed.scrollTop = 0;
```